# Mongodb retrieve conversation from messages

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, nosql

In my mongodb database i have a collection for messages that i use for sending private messages from user to user. I want to retrieve conversations of a user.
I have this data model:

**Updated json**

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("577f81fde4501ba208b0e470"),
   "text" : "This is a message",
   "sender_profile_id" : ObjectId("577e69b0794f49d962f10e85"),
   "receiver_profile_id" : ObjectId("577e57393db745060b532000"),
},    
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("577f81fde4501ba208b0e470"),
   "text" : "This is a message",
   "sender_profile_id" : ObjectId("577e57393db745060b532000"),
   "receiver_profile_id" : ObjectId("577e69b0794f49d962f10e85"),
},    
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("577f81fde4501ba208b0e470"),
   "text" : "This is a message",
   "sender_profile_id" : ObjectId("577e57393db745060b532000"),
   "receiver_profile_id" : ObjectId("577e69b0794f49d962f10e82"),
},  
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("577f81fde4501ba208b0e470"),
   "text" : "This is a message",
   "sender_profile_id" : ObjectId("577e69b0794f49d962f10e82"),
   "receiver_profile_id" : ObjectId("577e57393db745060b532000"),
},
```

With this json in theory i have 2 conversation for user ObjectId("577e57393db745060b532000"). How can i retrieve them?

**Updated solution**

I resolved with this:

```
var selector = {};
selector['$or'] = [
  {"sender_profile_id" : ObjectId(decoded.profile._id)},
  {"receiver_profile_id" : ObjectId(decoded.profile._id)}
];

selector['_acl'] = {$exists : true};
selector['_acl.' + decoded.profile._id] = {$exists : true};
selector['_acl.' + decoded.profile._id + '.read'] = true;

var query = {
  $match : selector
};

var group = {
  $group: {
    _id: "$_id",
    text : { $last: '$text' },
    sender_profile_id : { $last: '$sender_profile_id' },
    receiver_profile_id : { $last: '$receiver_profile_id' },
    receiver : {$addToSet : '$receiver_profile_id'},
    sender: {$addToSet : '$sender_profile_id'},
    created_at : { $last: '$created_at' },
    updated_at : { $last: '$updated_at' },
    count: { $sum: 1 }
  }
};

var project = {
  $project: {
    _id: "$_id",
    text: "$text",
    sender_profile_id: '$sender_profile_id',
    receiver_profile_id: '$receiver_profile_id',
    created_at : '$created_at',
    updated_at : '$updated_at',
    participants : {
      $cond: {
        if: {
          $gte: ["$sender", "$receiver"] },
          then: { "$setUnion": ["$receiver", "$sender"] },
          else:  { "$setUnion": ["$sender", "$receiver"] }
        }
      }
    }
  };

  var group2 =   {
    $group: {
      _id: "$participants",
      text : { $first: '$text' },
      sender_profile_id : { $first: '$sender_profile_id' },
      receiver_profile_id : { $first: '$receiver_profile_id' },
      created_at : { $first: '$created_at' },
      updated_at : { $first: '$updated_at' },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  };

var project2 = {
  $project: {
    _id : 0,
    participants : "$_id",
    text: "$text",
    interlocutor_profile_id: {
      $cond: {
        if: {"$eq": [ "$receiver_profile_id", ObjectId(decoded.profile._id)]},
        then: '$sender_profile_id',
        else: '$receiver_profile_id'
    }
  },
  created_at : 1,
  updated_at : 1,
  count: 1
  }
}

var sort = {
  $sort: {
      "created_at": -1
    }
}

var sort2 = {
  $sort: {
      "created_at": -1
    }
}

db.collection('message').aggregate(query, group, project, sort, group2, project2, sort2, function(error, result)
```

Comment: Try this : db.<collectionName>.find({$or: [{'sender._id': 'ObjectId("577e57393db745060b532000")'}, {'receiver._id': 'ObjectId("577e57393db745060b532000")'}]}).pretty();

Comment: let me know, if issue exist or i missed something

Comment: This can give you an idea.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35549200/mongo-group-and-sum-with-two-fields

Comment: @Jain i get all the documents with that code, instead i need the conversations.

Comment: i'm looking on these 5 records and all of these may contain this id either into sender or receiver column.

Comment: @Jain yes because the user can be the sender(who send the message) and the receiver(ho receive the message). If you see just the last record that have different receiver, so there must be 2 conversations from the user with id ObjectId("577e57393db745060b532000")

Comment: okay, sorry i missed up

Comment: db.<collectionName>.find({$or: [{'sender._id': 'ObjectId("577e57393db745060b532000")','receiver._id': 'ObjectId("577e69b0794f49d962f10e85")'},{'sender._id': 'ObjectId("577e69b0794f49d962f10e85")','receiver._id': 'ObjectId("577e57393db745060b532000")'}]}).pretty();

Comment: @Jain it work to get all documents based on the sender._id and receiver._id but this not what i needed. What i need is to find conversations for this user, so in my case should be 2 conversations. I know that using aggregate i can do it, but i'm using ObjectId for sender and receiver and i think is not possible.

Comment: yes it is possible. you can use groupby via aggregation.

Comment: @Jain How can i do that?

Comment: give me 5 minutes, i'm createing query for this.

Comment: try this: 
db.aggregate([
 {$match: {$or: [{'sender._id': 'ObjectId("577e57393db745060b532000")','receiver._id': 'ObjectId("577e69b0794f49d962f10e85")'},{'sender._id': 'ObjectId("577e69b0794f49d962f10e85")','receiver._id': 'ObjectId("577e57393db745060b532000")'}]}},
 {$group: { 
        _id: '$sender._id',
        vals: { '$push': '$receiver._id' }
    }}
])

Comment: @Jain it seam that is a good approach and is working, i will try it after a half hour and let you know.

Comment: sure, tell me correct answer too. :)

Comment: You should consider to post your solution in the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
db.aggregate([ {$match: {$or: [{'sender._id': 'ObjectId("577e57393db745060b532000")','receiver._id': 'ObjectId("577e69b0794f49d962f10e85")'},{'sender._id': 'ObjectId("577e69b0794f49d962f10e85")','receiver._id': 'ObjectId("577e57393db745060b532000")'}]}}, {$group: { _id: '$sender._id', vals: { '$push': '$receiver._id' } }} ])
```

Comment: I tried it but i changed some part and simplify the json using just the objectid as value of sender and receiver and in $or : [{ "sender" : ObjectId('577e57393db745060b532000')}, {"receiver" : ObjectId('577e57393db745060b532000')}]`, because i want to know the conversation from a user (the logged in user). Than with ` $group : {
          _id: '$sender',
          vals: { '$push': '$receiver' }
        }` i get just 1 result, but it should be 2...

Answer (score 0):

**Found a solution for my question:**

```
var selector = {};
selector['$or'] = [
 {"sender_profile_id" : ObjectId(decoded.profile._id)},
 {"receiver_profile_id" : ObjectId(decoded.profile._id)}
];

selector['_acl'] = {$exists : true};
selector['_acl.' + decoded.profile._id] = {$exists : true};
selector['_acl.' + decoded.profile._id + '.read'] = true;

var query = {
 $match : selector
};

var group = {
 $group: {
  _id: "$_id",
  text : { $last: '$text' },
  sender_profile_id : { $last: '$sender_profile_id' },
  receiver_profile_id : { $last: '$receiver_profile_id' },
  receiver : {$addToSet : '$receiver_profile_id'},
  sender: {$addToSet : '$sender_profile_id'},
  created_at : { $last: '$created_at' },
  updated_at : { $last: '$updated_at' },
  count: { $sum: 1 }
 }
};

var project = {
  $project: {
    _id: "$_id",
    text: "$text",
    sender_profile_id: '$sender_profile_id',
    receiver_profile_id: '$receiver_profile_id',
    created_at : '$created_at',
    updated_at : '$updated_at',
    participants : {
     $cond: {
       if: {
         $gte: ["$sender", "$receiver"] },
         then: { "$setUnion": ["$receiver", "$sender"] },
         else:  { "$setUnion": ["$sender", "$receiver"] }
       }
     }
   }
 };

var group2 =   {
 $group: {
  _id: "$participants",
  text : { $first: '$text' },
  sender_profile_id : { $first: '$sender_profile_id' },
  receiver_profile_id : { $first: '$receiver_profile_id' },
  created_at : { $first: '$created_at' },
  updated_at : { $first: '$updated_at' },
  count: { $sum: 1 }
 }
};

var project2 = {
 $project: {
  _id : 0,
  participants : "$_id",
  text: "$text",
  interlocutor_profile_id: {
   $cond: {
    if: {"$eq": [ "$receiver_profile_id", ObjectId(decoded.profile._id)]},
    then: '$sender_profile_id',
    else: '$receiver_profile_id'
  }
 },
 created_at : 1,
 updated_at : 1,
 count: 1
 }
}

var sort = {
 $sort: {
  "created_at": -1
 }
}

var sort2 = {
  $sort: {
   "created_at": -1
  }
}

db.collection('message').aggregate(query, group, project, sort, group2, project2, sort2, function(error, result)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following

```
db.messages.aggregate([{$project: {correspondents: {$cond: { if: {$gte: ["$sender", "$receiver"]}, then: ["$sender", "$receiver"], else: ["$receiver", "$sender"]}}}}, {$group: {_id: "$correspondents", messages: {$addToSet: "$_id"}}}, {$match: {"_id": ObjectId("577e57393db745060b532000")}}])
```

The query groups by pairs of conversation participants (correspondents) and returns an array of messages that comprise the conversation. Further, you can get the conversation belonging to a particular user.

Comment: i tried it, but it return an empty array. Like they are no conversations.

Comment: It is strange because I launched it on the portion of data you have posted in the question and received exactly two conversations. Did you launch it in a console?

Comment: No i'm using it with nodejs and running with backend calls

Comment: You can see this screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/mml88u0e4axa47q/Schermata%202016-07-09%20alle%2019.24.27.png?dl=0

Comment: Well, the problem may be in your calls then. Try the query in a console first, if it works for your data you may need to review the nodejs code.

Comment: I tried with robomongo too but it give to me 0 result.

Comment: Tried in robomongo, worked just fine. In case you just copy and paste the query I've suggested check the collection name it may differ from your collection name.

Comment: This is the command that i'm using:
db.getCollection('message').aggregate([{$project: {correspondents: {$cond: { if: {$gte: ["$sender", "$receiver"]}, then: ["$sender", "$receiver"], else: ["$receiver", "$sender"]}}}}, {$group: {_id: "$correspondents", messages: {$addToSet: "$_id"}}}, {$match: {"_id": ObjectId("577e57393db745060b532000")}}])

Comment: Your query is different from mine, just copy and paste the initial query. "$sender" and "$sender._id" is not the same.

Comment: If you see, i updated the question to make it more clear. So now i have receiver and sender for id.

Answer (score -1):

You can also check $lookup option. See below for illustrations 
http://dbversity.com/joins-in-mongodb-lookup/